# Xamarin Studio: Why does debugging the default app on an Android device cause the app to crash?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Studio for Mac to build a mobile application for iOS and Android.

I created the default (Welcome to Xamarin Forms!) Forms app. I tried both the Portable Class Library and the Shared Library with the following results:

- Running **release** build of the app on **iOS** device - **SUCCESS**
- Running **debug** build of the app on **iOS** device - **SUCCESS**
- Running **release** build of the app on **Android** device - **SUCCESS**
- Running **debug** build of the app on **Android** device - **FAILURE** (details below)
- Running **debug** build of the app on emulated **Android** device - **FAILURE** (details below)

**FAILURE**:
On the device, I simply get "MyApp has stopped" before the app has successfully started. In Xamarin Studio, I get no indication that anything has gone wrong.

Real Android device: Samsung S5 SM-G900-F

Emulated Android device: (Genymotion) Google Nexus 5X 7.0.0 API 24 (tried several others with the same results)

I tried setting a breakpoint on `InitializeComponent()` in `app.xaml.cs`. No hit. What am I missing here?

Oh, and this all works perfectly when running the same tests from Visual Studio on a Windows computer.

Comment: might help to view the device logs to see why the app is stopping. See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Comment: Thanks @jgoldberger - Fatal exception - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!

There is a stack trace as well and 10ms later, it force finishes the activity...

Comment: @jgoldberger not quite sure why this is happening though. The Nexus has API 24... Please let me know, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Just thought I should add: this all works perfectly when running the same tests from Visual Studio on a Windows computer.

Comment: I would suggest trying to delete the Mono Shared Runtime and any Xamarin Android API-XX Support from the installed apps. On your device go to Settings->Apps ( or App Manager on older devices) and look for those apps and uninstall them. Might not be a bad idea to delete your app as well for a clean start on the device.

Comment: @jgoldberger Thank you for the suggestion. I deleted the Mono Shared Runtime and Xamarin Android API-23 as well as the app from my physical device and from the emulated Nexus (for some reason also API-23 on the Nexus). Same result. Seeing as this all works fine from Visual Studio on a Windows computer, is there any reason to further troubleshoot the device?

Comment: Hmm. It might help to see the stack trace. But the message "Unable to find application Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_24 or Xamarin.Android.Platform!" would seem to indicate that those are not getting installed. Do you have the option to use the Shared Mono runtime selected in the project options? Fast Development option? Try turning the Fast Dev option off if it is on.