# Xamarin Debugging on Android Device not working

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an Xamarin project (On a Mac) that I'm working on. Up until today I was able to Launch it under debug, it would deploy the app and start it up attached so I could hit break points on the device. If I do this in an emulator, things work fine.

So when I run in Debug on Android, it deploys, I get no errors or messages that indicate an issue, but it just stops and is no longer running.

So what I've done

- I've uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio, no change
- I've tried on multiple devices, with different OS versions
- I've reset my project to be the same as others on the team, they have no issue
- I've verified that the same project works fine on my Windows machine.
- I've verified that I can run a Release version with no problem, I hit run, it deploys and launches the app just fine.
- I can deply the iOS version in an emulator with no problems.
- I've verified that if I set Debug Information to Full in the Release project, I have the same issue.
- I've rebooted the device, the Mac, uninstalled the app on the device, it doesn't matter.

I'm at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Settings on the devices themselves? Do the same devices work for other team members? Are you getting any feedback from the device? I’m not familiar with VS, but *could* you attach a LogCat to the device and see if the device is killing your app?

Comment: Same device, same app on a PC it runs fine, just not on a Mac

Comment: @GR, you mean that your have xamarin project on mac, when you debug this xamarin project to android device, it stops and you don't get any error message?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Yes. I launch a debug variant of the application, it builds and deploys to the device, but the session ends as soon as the deploy finishes. It never shows up or launches on the device and the run ends.  

I have use Time Machine and reverted back to an older system that was working.  I couldn't figure this out and had to revert.

Comment: @GR,You said that debug this project in emulator, it works fine, so I think your project have no issue, do you try to debug in other android device? It have the same issue?

Comment: Yes,all devices had the same issue

Comment: @GR, It is so strange, I suggest you can create one thread at Github for more discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of things that connecting and deploying your app require, including setting the configuration and making sure you have the ADB installed correctly. You can check on Mac by following [these](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging) steps to install Chrome and DevTools.

[Another user suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804821/xamarin-studio-why-does-debugging-the-default-app-on-an-android-device-cause-th?r=SearchResults)(in the comments under question):
"I would suggest trying to delete the Mono Shared Runtime and any Xamarin Android API-XX Support from the installed apps" on your targeted device.

[These are the docs on Configuration Management in Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/configuration-management)
on Microsoft.com

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late answer but I had same problem and could solve it so may be it could be helpful for over people facing same problem.

Android csproj file must be located two levels lower than the .sln file. Android will disconnect when debugging if it is located in another location.

> For example:
>
> C:\Projects\Mobile\My.Xamarin.sln
>   C:\Projects\Mobile\My.Xamarin\My.Xamarin.Android\My.Xamarin.Android.csproj